# Windows Phone 8.1 Downloaded Maps

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I have a small question about downloaded maps in Windows Phone 8.1. Is it possible to detect in code if the user has a downloaded map for a particular country? The idea is to suggest the user to download the map, so the Application runs faster and the user saves some wifi or network data
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two classes that will help the user to understand the Offline Maps content, but there is no known way to do this only in C#.

The two options are:

- MapUpdaterTask: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206975(v=vs.105).aspx
- MapDownloaderTask: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206984(v=vs.105).aspx

This will load the Maps Settings app but not directly give you hint on code.

I did not try but you might be able to perform local request (find/geocoding or route) and observe the result to see if there are specific properties or values that might differ while calculating in offline.